# printf() inside while loop won't print unless integer is instantiated first

Tags: c, printf, mingw

I am experiencing really weird behavior when attempting to print the contents of a text file (test_input.txt) after I redirect it to the stdin of this main.exe program I compiled with mingw on windows 10. It will print fine if I instantiate an integer before the while loop, but nothing otherwise.

test_input.txt:

```
2
3
5 1 2
6
1 3 3 2 2 15
```

main.c that prints nothing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXTESTS 100
#define MAXPAPERS 10000

int main(){
    char*ptr;
    while(fgets(ptr,MAXPAPERS*2,stdin)){
        printf("%s",ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
C:\temp>gcc -o main.exe main.c

C:\temp>main.exe < test_input.txt

C:\temp>
```

main.c that does print:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXTESTS 100
#define MAXPAPERS 10000

int main(){
    char*ptr;
    int whatever = 0;
    while(fgets(ptr,MAXPAPERS*2,stdin)){
        printf("%s",ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
C:\temp>gcc -o main.exe main.c

C:\temp>main.exe < test_input.txt
2
3
5 1 2
6
1 3 3 2 2 15
C:\temp>
```

Comment: `ptr` is never initialized so you get Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It's not initialized *and* no memory is allocated for it, so you're reading bytes from a file into random memory.

Comment: If your mingw build of gcc supports sanitizers, add `-fsanitize=address` to the compilation flags and run your program again.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, very true, it does work now. Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your read buffer. `char ptr[MAXPAPERS*2+1]` or even better, something big enough to contain the whole file if necessary.